# String split on newline creates blank strings for every newline

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, split

I have a split on a newline which works fine, but it seems to create a blank value for every time it does a split, so 'MyText' contains the following values, separated by a newline:

```
Blue
Green
Yellow
```

And my split is as below

```
List<string> options = myText.split('[\r\n]');
```

I instead of ending up with 3 'options' I end up with 5 like this - a blank for each newline:

```
Blue,'',Green,'',Yellow
```

Other than ignoring the blank values in a loop, how can I avoid the split creating the blanks in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If you split the string without the brackets, it works properly:

```
String myText = 'Blue\r\n'
              + 'Green\r\n'
              + 'Yellow';

List<string> options = myText.split('\r\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a regex to `.split()` for it to determine what to split on.

`[]` indicates a class of characters to match on.

so `[\r\n]` is telling you to split on a single character, either `\r` *or `\n`*.
It does not say "find an `\r` followed by `\n`". If your string happens to have both, then

```
Blue\r\nGreen
```

will turn into

```
"Blue",\nGreen
```

then

```
"Blue", "", Green
```

and so on

Keeping in mind that not every OS uses `\r\n` for line ends (it's pretty much just Windows that does that, I believe), the regex you want to use in `.split()` is `\r?\n`.

That's a carriage return (`\r`), which may or may not exist (`?`), followed immediately by a newline (`\n`)